# Hadoop installation on asymmetric OS?

Tags: hadoop, operating-system, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have Cent OS on two nodes and Ubuntu on other two nodes can i install Cloudera 4.5 or later on the servers.

i have searched on internet but could not find any relevant information.

How can i install Cloudera on these 4 servers?

Answer (score 0):

No we can not install Hadoop on a cluster having heterogeneous OS.

This is one of the limitation of Hadoop.